# Error on the Hosting server in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Please I have an asp.net mvc 5 web app hosted at SmarterASP.NET 
My web app allows users to upload an image file and my code base creates a directory to upload the file to, when I run it locally it works very fine, but when running on the server, I get an error saying `access to the file path has been denied`, I contacted SmarterASP and I was told it will be a better option if I consult a developer. So I thought of sharing my problem here if anyone can help, I have checked the file permissions on the server and everything is cool, so I still do not know why, am getting that error, any help will be highly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: hope you have given full folder permission for IIS_Users

Comment: The problem might be the app pool not having enough permissions.

Comment: Check your IIS app pool's identity. Check what file path it is. Check if the app pool's identity has the permission.

Comment: It is only permission issue. Just ask them to give full permission and it will fix your issue.